# Adding a dataframe column to a specific position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am extracting a column from my dataframe, so i can process the features in the remaining dataframe columns and storing it inside a variable. What i would like to do is return that column back to it's position, for example:

Original dataframe:

```
samples = {'col1': [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12],
        'col2': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        'col3': [10, 15, 16, 17, 19, 12, 10, 31],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(samples, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Storing the first column inside df_col1

```
df_col1 = df.iloc[:, 0:0]
df = df.iloc[:, 1:]
```

What i would like to do is add the column inside `df_col1` back to it's original position inside my data frame `df` as it was originally.

Comment: how will the current program know what the original position was? is it recorded in some variable in your script?

Comment: Use: `df = df[[‘list’, ‘of’, ‘ordered’, ‘col’, ‘names’]]`

Comment: Also, your call to store the first column into `df_col1` actually just makes an empty dataframe. You want `df_col1 = df.iloc[:,0:1]`

Comment: No, i want to manually insert the position. It will be always at index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you know where the position was (you stored it somewhere), or happy to specify the position directly, let's say you want it in pos 0, use (after you removed it in your code)

```
df.insert(0,df_col1.columns[0], df_col1)
```

Comment: I tried it before, IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: works for me. perhaps `df_col1 = df.iloc[:, 0:0]` was giving you trouble as @cookesd mentioned, you want `df_col1 = df.iloc[:, 0:1]`

Comment: oh yeah, it works for me now, thats why it wasn't working before. thanks

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame.insert(loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=False)
loc is insertation index